# Create HSTORE with multiple schemas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I have been trying to migrate my database to have HSTORE but the extension only works for **public** SCHEMA when I want to add an HSTORE column in other schemas it does not work

```
def up
  # My hstore looks like this
  execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore SCHEMA public"
  # I have also tried
  # execute "CREATE EXTENSION hstore"
end
```

but when I run my next migration it just doesn't work and if I go to psql console and alter tables I get this:

```
set search_path to public;
alter table accounts add column extras hstore; -- Works fine
set search_path to schema2;
alter table accounts add column extras hstore; -- Raises an error
```

I'm using rails 4
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to refer to your objects in a way that is consistent with your schema naming and search path.  For example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore SCHEMA public;

SET search_path TO schema2;
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD COLUMN extras public.hstore;
```

or

```
SET search_path TO public;
ALTER TABLE schema2.accounts ADD COLUMN extras hstore;
```

Comment: **Important** note, when you change the _schema_ you must always use the public path to change so **hstore** is loaded `SET SEARCH_PATH TO schema2, public`

Answer (score 5):

If you're using multiple different schemas, I suggest putting `hstore` in its own and ensuring it is always on the `search_path`. You might not want `public` on your `search_path` at all times, and it's nice to keep things compartmentalized.

```
CREATE SCHEMA hstore;
CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH SCHEMA hstore;
```

... then either amend your `search_path` consistently, or just always schema-qualify everything, using `hstore.hstore` as the type name, `OPERATOR(hstore.->)`. E.g.

```
SELECT hstore.hstore('"x" => "42"') OPERATOR(hstore.->) "x"
```

Alternately, it's safe to install `hstore` into `pg_catalog`:

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
```

`pg_catalog` is always implicitly on the search path.

Comment: Didn't know about putting the hstore ext in pg_catalog. Thanks!

Comment: wow, can you follow people on SO :) ? This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

the alternative to Peter Eisentraut's answer is to amend your search path so that the public schema is always on the search path.

This is particularly useful if you rely on schemas for a multitenant app (which is my case).

In your `database.yml` file you would put the following instruction:

`schema_search_path: "schema2, public"`

note: put your main schema first.

if you want to change the search path in a more dynamic way in your code, you can play with `connection.schema_search_path`