# Migration wont recognize hstore extension created on schema_search_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations, hstore, apartment-gem

I´m trying to add a column using postgresql HStore.

Since I´m running a multi tenant app (using apartment gem), I´ve created the hstore extension on a dedicated schema, called "shared_extensions", as seen here: [https://github.com/influitive/apartment#installing-extensions-into-persistent-schemas][1]

I also added the shared_extensions schema to database.yml as:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  schema_search_path: "public,shared_extensions"
```

However, when I try to run rake db:migrate to add hstore column, I´m still receiving the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "hstore" does not exist
```

This is the hstore migration code:

```
class AddAdditionalInformationsToParties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :parties, :additional_informations, :hstore
  end
end
```

I´m not sure, but it looks like migrations are not recognizing the schema_search_path on database.yml file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable the hstore extension in postgres.

Try running `rails g migration add_hstore_extension`, then edit it like below:

`class AddHstoreExtension < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    enable_extension "hstore"
  end
  def self.down
    disable_extension "hstore"
  end
end`

Note that you'll need that to run *before* the migration which uses it.

Comment: Hey Chris,

This works on a sample app I have created.

However, I´m using multiple postgresql schemas to run a multi-tenant app.
As soon as I try to use hstore on another schema, I run into the same error.

This is why I came with the option to create a specific schema just for hstore extension, and then try to put it on search_path for all other schemas.

Comment: The solution I´m trying to implement is the one written here:

https://github.com/influitive/apartment#installing-extensions-into-persistent-schemas

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the extension to pg_catalog, which is always implicitly on search_path, as described by Craig Ringer in this post:

[Create HSTORE with multiple schemas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790242/create-hstore-with-multiple-schemas)

```
CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH SCHEMA pg_catalog;
```